# Why does system call affect subsequent print behaviour in perl?

Tags: perl, buffer, system-calls, tcsh

Here's my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
system('wc -l $file');
print "\nprinting alpha \n";
sleep 1;
exit;
```

After I run (in `tcsh` shell) `perl script.pl /path/to/file` I don't see `printing alpha` until I press `Ctrl+C`. Even when I add another statement `$|=1` either before or after system call, the behaviour remains the same.

What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are executing the shell command

```
wc -l $file
```

The shell has no variable `$file` defined, so that's the same as

```
wc -l
```

This causes the shell to execute `wc` with the lone arg `-l`. With no file name provided, `wc` in turn reads from STDIN until you kill it with SIGINT from Ctrl-C.

---

You were perhaps aiming for

```
system("wc -l $file");   # XXX
```

but that's wrong too. That doesn't pass the args `-l` and the value of `$file` to `wc`. Consider what would happen if a file name with a space in it was provided.

To build a shell literal that results in the correct file name, you could use

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
system(shell_quote('wc', '-l', $file));
```

But a better option is to avoid the shell and execute `wc` directly, passing to it the values you want without having to build a shell command.

```
system('wc', '-l', $file);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the single quotes prevent interpolation of `$file`.  Change to double quotes.

What is happening is that the string is being executed without substituting a value for `$file`. When the shell gets this it looks for a shell variable `$file` which does not exist, so it executes the command with no file. This causes `wc` to read from stdin, resulting in the behavior you see.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I had to accept the other one as it informed more, but yours is fine too.